# How to correct the code formatting of a problem if it leads to the question being just code?

Tags: support

I was editing the code in this particular question: https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/26331682

The content of this post is just code but hasn't been code formatted and formatting it correctly means that the validation check won't allow me to edit since it is just code. What would be the correct course of action in such a case?

> Question

fun sortBubble(array:Array):Array{
var temp: Long

```
for(i in 0 until array.size){
    for (j in 0 until array.size-i-1){

        if (array[j] > array[j+1]){
            temp = array[j]
            array[j] = array[j+1]
            array[j+1] = temp
        }
    }
}

return array
```

}

fun main(args: Array) {
HOW CAN I ADD
}

> Formatted code

```kotlin
fun sortBubble(array:Array<Long>):Array<Long>{
    var temp: Long

    for(i in 0 until array.size){
        for (j in 0 until array.size-i-1){

            if (array[j] > array[j+1]){
                temp = array[j]
                array[j] = array[j+1]
                array[j+1] = temp
            }
        }
    }

    return array
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    HOW CAN I ADD
}
```

**Please note: this is editing the question while reviewing it not a question I have asked**

Comment: If the question is just code, then they don't have a problem statement, so instead of editing it you should vote/flag as "needs details or clarity."

Comment: @JohnMontgomery what if the title and the comments are explanatory?

Comment: In this particular case, they aren't, but if they were, then I would try to rephrase them in non-code text.

Comment: And if doing so moving comments to the question *explain that that is the source of the edit clearly in the edit summary for the reviewers*